# Javascript - ES6 : addEventListener call a class methode with paramteter is not working

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, parameters, addeventlistener

here is the Link to run the Problem: [runningExample](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSI2ULLAP1CQ)

I create a Class:

```
class button {

    constructor(){       

        var button_id = 99;

        document.getElementById("bu1")
            .addEventListener( "click", this.bu_clicked(button_id) );
    }

    bu_clicked(button_id){
        alert("Hallo: " + button_id);
    }       

}
```

in which I add a addEventListener for a click on a button:

```
<button style="width:50px; height:50px;" id="bu1" ></button>
```

The problem is that it's not working correctly with the paramter "button_id" in the class call "this.bu_clicked()". By starting the Script the methode "bu_clicked" will be instantly called.

If I leave off the parameter like this, "this.bu_clicked" it's working, but I need that paramter!

Greetings

Comment: where do you instantiate the new button class?

Comment: the instantiate is done in "window.onload" event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [Gabriel Carneiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6565510/gabriel-carneiro)'s answer, you don't necessarily have to pass the `id` to the click handling function. You can just get it from the `this` object as `this` refers to the button itself.

```js
window.onload = function() {  
  obj_button = new button();
};
    
// Option list class
class button {
  constructor(){
    var button_id = 99;
    const button1 = document.getElementById("bu1");
    const button2 = document.getElementById("bu2");
    button1.dataset.buttonId = button_id;
    button2.dataset.buttonId = 100;
    button1.addEventListener( "click", this.bu_clicked );
    button2.addEventListener( "click", this.bu_clicked );
  }

  bu_clicked(e){
    const button = this; // refers to the object that the handler is bound to.
    const button_id = button.dataset.buttonId;
    alert("Hallo: " + button_id);
  }
}
```

```html
<button style="width:50px; height:50px;" id="bu1">Click me</button>    
<button style="width:50px; height:50px;" id="bu2">Click me as well</button>
```

Comment: thank you this worked great, classes add a lot more complexity than function and `new`. not sure if it is worth all of the extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
class button {

    constructor(){       

        var button_id = 99;

        document.getElementById("bu1")
            .addEventListener( "click", () => { this.bu_clicked(button_id); });
    }

    bu_clicked(button_id){
        alert("Hallo: " + button_id);
    }       

}
```

The `.addEventListener` expects a string and a function, you're passing the return of the `this.bu_clicked` that is `undefined`. If you write as I did, you're passing a closure that calls the `this.bu_clicked` passing the `button_id`. (PS: the curly brackets are optional, I put it just to be easier to understand)

Answer (score -1):

You should `bind` the handler to the element:

```
    document.getElementById("bu1")
        .addEventListener("click", this.bu_clicked.bind(button_id));
```

Comment: You don't need `bind` in classes

Comment: That is not the case, He is passing the return of the function, not the function itself